# HERE SDK APIs for android studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to use HERE Android SDK Turn-by-Turn Navigation.

Can I use HERE SDK for free?? Not only for 90 days as it is written in the [Developer.Here.com](https://developer.here.com/plans/mobile-sdk)

please any help

Answer (score 0):

No, the HERE Mobile SDK for Android is a commercial product, with a evaluation period of 90 days, afterwards it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

The maps component won't work in your application. The data stored will remain stored and all the other functionality will stay unaffected. If your application is all about the maps, it will become usable.

I'm blessed with a company account so I don't have to worry about that. However, I've been told that the issue can be "resolved" by simply registering a new account and obtaining a new key. Of course, it's a pain to re-register your application but it's free.

Or you can go with another provider that's "eternally" free. However, HereMaps have the ambition to beat all the others so sticking to them might prove wise.