# Issue with HERE Sdk APIs

Tags: android, here-api

I want to try **HERE** Android SDK with Premium Evaluation version, I read it's for 90-day free trial .

before i give it try i want to know what will happen after 90 trail days complete?
is my android application will stop working or what does that mean ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869575/here-sdk-apis-for-android-studio

Comment: there is no answer @Rotwang

Comment: Probably, because it's not a good question.

Comment: it's not good question for you but it's important for us,sorry for that but really we don't know the answer. if you have the answer said yes or no maybe you will safe us, You will not lose anything

Comment: I don't know the answer. But this site is for questions like `"I have this code. The desired behavior is this, instead I get this error. How can I solve that?"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HERE MobileSDK will stop working after 90 days when your trial license expires. Means your map engine doesn't get initialized anymore and you can't use any of the SDK features. So not seeing a map canvas, can't calculate a route or start guidance. The rest of your app (that's not using the HERE SDK) is of course not impacted.

Comment: thank you for reply, excuse me can you tell like what services or features which can not be impacted, if i will not be able to see the map so what will be left !

Comment: Everything from HERE MobileSDK will stop working after 90 days. This SDK is not just a mapcanvas. Beside the mapview, you have tons of other geospatial services within the HERE MobileSDk that you necessarily don't need to use on a map. For example car/truck/walk routing, turn by turn voice navigation, reverse/geocoding, streetlevel imagery, satellite images, places search, public transit features, and so on....

Answer (score 0):

The maps won't work in your application. The data stored will remain in the cache according to the settings of your system. Your application will function in all regards except the GIS (which, I'd guess **is** everything to it, so in practice the app will not be usable).

I'm blessed with a company account so I don't have to worry about that. However, I've been told that the issue can be "resolved" by simply registering a new account and obtaining a new key. Of course, it's a pain to re-register your application but it's free.

Or you can go with another provider that's "eternally" free. However, HereMaps have the ambition to beat all the others so sticking to them might prove wise.